# Conditionally select a single character in regex using lookahead/lookbehind?

Tags: regex

I am making a code-cleanup tool that will automatically format my code to my company's C++ code style standards.
One such standard is that method names must have a space before the `(`.

```
void Method (...);
```

I want to use a regex to match such parentheses so that I may replace `(` with `(`.

Since this is only for method signatures, I want to ignore strings such as `if(...)`, `while(...)`, etc.

My idea is to use a negative lookahead to make sure that the line doesn't contain a "C++ word"

```
^(?!if|for|switch|do|while).+(\()
```

and use a negative lookbehind to make sure that the `(` is not preceded by a space.

```
(?<! )\(
```

These do the trick individually, but I am having difficulty combining them. 
Firstly, is this a reasonable approach? Is there a better way?

More importantly, how can I select my `(`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookbehind assertion.

```
(?<!\b(if|for|switch|do|while))\(
```

or

```
(?<!\bif|\bfor|\bswitch|\bdo|\bwhile)\(
```

or

```
(?<!\s)(?<!\bif|\bfor|\bswitch|\bdo|\bwhile)\(
```

Replace with:

```
 (
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yC2vT8/1)